# Crear JLabels dentro de un for y asignar nombre de variables en Java

Tags: java, java-swing, jlabel

Necesito crear varios JLabels dentro de un for, de forma indefinida, tiene que crearlos en un int que le da el usuario. Por ejemplo, si el usuario le asigna 10, el for debe ser recorrido 10 veces y por cada recorrido del for debe crearse un nuevo JLabel. El problema es que a estos JLabels tengo que tratarlos de forma distinta, por lo que necesito cambiar su nombre, por ejemplo Label1, Label2, etc, pero no sé cómo hacerlo. Alguien podría ayudarme?

Comment: Y qué has intentado hasta el momento? Aquí no resolvemos tareas escolares. Aquí ayudamos con problemas específicos. Por favor has el [tour] y lee [ask] y [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Coloca el código de lo que has intentado hasta el momento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Diste muy poca información, pero con lo que dices se me ocurre esto, si te sirve aquí está:

```java
Map<String, JLabel> map = new HashMap<String, JLabel>();
for(int i = 0; i <= numeroIndefinido; i++){
    map.put("label"+i, new JLabel("Nose?"));
}
//....
var labelEspecifico = map.get("label1"); //label0, label1, label2, ...
```

Si gustas puedes hacer lo mismo con números

```java
Map<Integer, JLabel> map = new HashMap<Integer, JLabel>();
for(int i = 0; i <= numeroIndefinido; i++){
   map.put(i, new JLabel("Nose?"));
}
//....
var labelEspecifico = map.get(0); //0, 1, 2, 3, ...
```

También con una lista.

```java
List<JLabel> list = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
for(int i = 0; i <= numeroIndefinido; i++){
   list.add(i, new JLabel("Nose?"));
}
//....
var labelEspecifico = list.get(0); //0, 1, 2, 3, ...
```

Creas el `label` dentro de una colección y luego lo recuperas donde lo necesites. Creo que esto es lo que necesitas.